# How can I dynamically inject different providers with Nest.js?

Tags: oop, nestjs

I'm facing the following issue. I have a service used by a controller. The service (in the snippets below QueueService) injects a provider imported from a package. I aim to reuse the QueueService across the controller methods, but I also need to dynamically specify which provider QueueService should use.

My question is, how can I achieve this behaviour?

```js
import { PubsubService } from '@myorg/queue'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
        SHARED_RESOURCES_PROJECT_ID: Joi.string().required()
      })
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'PUBSUB',
      useValue: new PubsubService()
    },
    {
      provide: 'INTEGRATION_PUBSUB',
      useValue: new PubsubService({ projectId: process.env.SHARED_RESOURCES_PROJECT_ID })
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private queueService: QueueService) {}

  @Post()
  async create() {
    ...

    // here I want to use queueService with `PUBSUB` injected
    return this.queueService.sendMessage(...)
  }

  @Patch()
  async update() {
    ...

    // here I want to use queueService with `INTEGRATION_PUBSUB` injected
    return this.queueService.sendMessage(...)
  }
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class QueueService {
  constructor(
    // how can I dynamically change `@Inject('PUBSUB')` to `@Inject('INTEGRATION_PUBSUB')`?
    @Inject('PUBSUB') private readonly pubsubService: PubsubService
  ) {}

  async sendMessage(payload): Promise<void> {
    return this.pubsubService.sendMessage(payload)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not just have `create` and `update` methods on QueueService and direct it that way (e.g. the caller is calling something different)? You need to trigger *something* differently from the caller's side otherwise there is no "reason" for the service to do anything differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamic inject is not possible after object(in this case controller) created . so you have two option

1- create two QueueService (one for PUBSUB  and another for INTEGRATION_PUBSUB) and inject both to controller. use those in your controller functions. (i recommend this)

2- inject both PUBSUB and INTEGRATION_PUBSUB into QueueService and pass another param in sendMessage function . so check this param to choose between PUBSUB and INTEGRATION_PUBSUB

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware that I can do things you mentioned, but I was looking for a "cleaner" solution. Anyway, think I will go with your advice and stop wasting time on this

Comment: I am also facing this issue. My case is that I want support mulitple versions of a client api. so depends on client is on (v1 or v2), I will need to call PUBSUBv1 or PUBSUBV2 in my controller. (PUBSUBV1 and PUBSUBv2 are actually same api service for different version)